# Spring RestTemplate 404 error for large POST request to .NET Core REST api

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asp.net-web-api, resttemplate

I am trying to make a Java (Spring) application which invokes a REST api in a .NET Core application. Everything seems to work in the general case, but now that I am making a POST with an XML string which takes up 80 megabytes on my system, the RestTemplate produces a 404 error code saying "Not found". I have tried to remove the POST size limit in both the .NET Core application (by using the `DisableRequestSizeLimit` attribute in the API controller) and in the Spring configuration (by setting the variable `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size` to 200MB in application.properties). Neither of it seems to work. Is there some way to fix this? I am willing to use an alternative to the RestTemplate, if that would make sense. I am using the `exchange` method of the RestTemplate object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to Milton BO's answer, I made a request in POSTMAN, which gave me a more detailed error response from the ASP.NET Core app. And it told me to change the maximum allowed post size in the web.config (or appplicationhost.config) file for IIS Express. Furthermore, I am now using the Kestrel server instead of IIS Express, so the DisableRequestSizeLimit attribute now works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Not found is a general error, if the problem would be sending the request, other problem will happens. I highly recommend you to test the rest api with another tool, like Postman or Insomnia. After that works with the tool try with your client application.

**Clarification:**
**spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size** is for api in your Spring application, no for requesting another services.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with using Postman. It allowed me to get the web page fail response generated by ASP.NET which gave me a more detailed error (an error code 404.13 and a description). It showed me that I had to edit my web.config file such that greater request were allowed by the ASP.NET api. Furthermore, by using the Kestrel web server instead of IIS Express, the DisableRequestSizeLimit works instead of making the change in web.config

Comment: Good, it is very helpfull to test rest api with external tools like Postman.